# How to call the ScrollView from the Alert in reactNative (Integration of AlertView and ScrollView )

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call the ScrollView from the Alert in reactNative (Integration of AlertView and ScrollView) but I am not able to integrate.

Here is the code link for AlertView,  triggering the showAlert function.:-
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_alert.htm

```
import React from 'react'
import { Alert, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const AlertExample = () => {
   const showAlert = () =>{
      Alert.alert(
         'How can I call the scrollView'
      )
   }
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress = {showAlert} style = {styles.button}>
         <Text>Alert</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   )
}
export default AlertExample

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   button: {
      backgroundColor: '#4ba37b',
      width: 100,
      borderRadius: 50,
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 100
   }
})
```

Code for ScrollView. Scrollview will render a list of names. We will create it in state :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

class ScrollViewExample extends Component {
   state = {
      names: [
         {'name': 'Ben', 'id': 1},
         {'name': 'Susan', 'id': 2},
         {'name': 'Robert', 'id': 3},
         {'name': 'Mary', 'id': 4},
         {'name': 'Daniel', 'id': 5},
         {'name': 'Laura', 'id': 6},
         {'name': 'John', 'id': 7},
         {'name': 'Debra', 'id': 8},
         {'name': 'Aron', 'id': 9},
         {'name': 'Ann', 'id': 10},
         {'name': 'Steve', 'id': 11},
         {'name': 'Olivia', 'id': 12}
      ]
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <ScrollView>
               {
                  this.state.names.map((item, index) => (
                     <View key = {item.id} style = {styles.item}>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                     </View>
                  ))
               }
            </ScrollView>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default ScrollViewExample

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   item: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: 30,
      margin: 2,
      borderColor: '#2a4944',
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#d2f7f1'
   }
})
```

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far, instead of posting links to tutorials or screenshots of code.

Comment: I am not able to add the code so posted link.

Comment: You can type that in the question itself

Comment: I have edited the question.